# download file from url on other Server "Host Download" - asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download, host

For downloading files from my server I use this method in asp.net MVC:

```
string fileName = "SAMSUNG.zip";
string path = @"D:\Tutorial MVC5\ContosoUniversity\ContosoUniversity\dlfile\";
string fullPath = path + fileName;
Response.Clear();
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.WriteFile(fullPath);
Response.End();
```

But, what about when I want to download files from another server, for example from a "host download". How can I do that? For example my download direct link is: `http://dl.test.com/file.zip`,
now user clicks a link `<a href="http://test.com/1">file.zip</a>` is to download the file. Now I want to send `file.zip` to the user without a user knowing where my trusted link is and where my host download is. She or he just chooses the file to download.

Thanks for help!

Comment: That's not an asp.net MVC way of downloading files.

Comment: what have you tried..? this is not that difficult.. are you familiar with `WebClient` Class..? I will post an example of what I think you aretrying to do..

Comment: @user2310064 why can't you use the example and pass the URL as a Param.. otherwise how else do you expect to pass the URL to the end user..?

Answer (score 3):

are you familiar with how to use and or Set `Request.Params` 
your url originally should look like this if you want to check the QueryString

`http://dl.test.com?file_name=SAMSUNG.zip`

```
if(Request.Params["file_name"] == "SAMSUNG.zip"
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://dl.test.com/file.zip");
    using (var wc = new WebClient())
    using (var download = wc.OpenRead(uri))
    using (var respStream = Response.OutputStream)
    {
        download.CopyTo(respStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: no i don't want to download file  i want just give a direct link to user for download file but he or she unknown where is truth link ??

Comment: Hi, Code is running fine but from from where i get the downloaded file ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i used the next Code in .net Core 5

```
[HttpGet("Descargar")]
public FileResult Descargar(string url,string nombre)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    Stream downloadStream = wc.OpenRead(uri);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    downloadStream.CopyTo(ms);
        
    return File(ms.ToArray(), System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, nombre);
}
```