# respond a url for download file with other server with WebClient.GetWebResponse Method or other Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, web, download

I have:

1.Host Download (there is all my file , i want to share them)
  2. localhost server (simple)

I have file: test.zip on SERVER 1 (HostDownload - Direct Link ex:http://dl.test.net/test.zip) AND I want to  response download link       for download file by user   in SERVER 2 using function but The user does not know the actual address 
 i writhed this but not work :

```
public WebResponse GetWebRequest()
{
     string address =(@"http://dl.test.net/test.zip");
     WebRequest request =WebRequest.Create(address);
     request.Method = "POST";
     request.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
     WebResponse response1 = request.GetResponse();
     return response1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download file from url on other Server "Host Download" - asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835563/download-file-from-url-on-other-server-host-download-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: what does `I writhed this but not work` mean..? you asked a similar question about this on Tuesday of last week what happens when you step through this code and use the debugger..?

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually your question is not clear, but as what that I'v realized you have to make an HTTP GET request to do that(download a file with http). I suggest "RestSharp" for HTTP requests, you can install this package with this command "Install-Package RestSharp" in your project "NugetPackageManager". This is a sample to do that with RestSharp:

```
        public byte[] GetWebRequest()
        {
           var client = new RestClient("http://dl.test.net/test.zip");
           var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
           IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
           var BytesOfFile = response.RawBytes;
           return BytesOfFile;
        }
```

then in server 2 user can converts Arry of Bytes to file with :

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C://downloadedData.zip", GetWebRequest());
```

Hope that helps you (/_-)